# Log4net: Multiple loggers single appender

Tags: log4net

I have multiple loggers referencing the same (rolling file) appender.
Only the first logger's output is appearing in the file.

Is it possible to make the appender work with multiple loggers? (I suppose not, but have not found any info in the docs, so need to confirm).

(I know there's logger inheritance, but I'm asking about non-inherited "independent" loggers)

My logger configuration is as follows

```
    <logger name="a.b.c.Class1">
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="DebugAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ErrorsAppender"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="a.b.c.Class2">
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="DebugAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ErrorsAppender"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="a.b.c.Class3">
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="DebugAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ErrorsAppender"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="a.b.c.Class4">
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="DebugAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ErrorsAppender"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="a.d.e.Class5">
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="DebugAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ErrorsAppender"/>
    </logger>
```

My appender configuratoin is as follows

```
   <appender name="DebugAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="C:/Debug.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <maximumFileSize value="256KB" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="Event: %d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%nProperties: %properties%n%n" />
      </layout>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
        <levelMax value="FATAL" />
      </filter>
    </appender>
    <appender name="ErrorsAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="C:/Errors.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <maximumFileSize value="256KB" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <param name="Threshold" value="WARN" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="Event: %d [%t] %-5p %c %stacktrace - %m%nProperties: %properties%n%n" />
      </layout>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="WARN" />
        <levelMax value="FATAL" />
      </filter>
    </appender>
```

The Log4net configuration is loaded with the regular

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure()
```

Comment: Please post your configs for all applicable loggers.

Comment: I've added the configuration.

Comment: Please also include sample code for how you construct the loggers and hook them up.

Comment: Added the configuration code.

Comment: If you add log4net debugging, are any errors generated? http://log4net.sourceforge.net/release/1.2.0.30316/doc/manual/faq.html#internalDebug